# Qt Application streching on meego after random time

Tags: c++, qt, xorg, meego

I am running a Qt application on Meego platform. The application is streching to full screen after random amount of clicks on application. After streching, even Xorg also gets corrupt. After restarting meego the application comes back to normal state. Can anybody faced similar issue ever?

Comment: you may have something calling `showFullScreen()` ... have you tried debugging or can you post your code related to handling click events?

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume that this is with Meegotouch UX ?  If so, "stretching" is a feature, touch ux does not support applications that do not fit fully into screen.  X corruption might be a bug in mcompositor. Any change you could dig up the versions of libmeegotouch and mcompositor ?